# Rails: Is it possible to create data inline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, best-in-place

I'm generating a calendar via Ryan Bates example: http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised

Is it possible to perform inline data creation within each day via some gem like best_in_place? (For example, entering work hours in a day which has no record yet.)

Comment: What do you mean by "inline data creation"? Do you mean create a new  entry in the Calendar, save it without reloading the page and displays it when the server saved it? (same with update/delete) If that's what you want, yes it is possible, the gem best_in_place could help you with that, but there is several ways to do it (I personaly prefer the Modal-boxes appearing on top of my Calendar displaying a form to edit/create an Event)

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like.